# UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException has been thrown when I try to open my app settings on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, monogame

I have created a button in my game's menu.cs to display if push notifications are enabled or not. When the user clicks on this button then my game's settings on iOS should open so that the user can change the push notification settings manually.

I use the following code in my menu.cs(located in a shared code project for iOS/Android) but I always get an exception:

```
        UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetNotificationSettings((settings) =>
            {
                if (settings.AuthorizationStatus == UNAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined || settings.AuthorizationStatus == UNAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
                {
                    var nurl = NSUrl.FromString(UIApplication.OpenNotificationSettingsUrl);
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(nurl!, new NSDictionary(), null);  
                }
                else
                {
                }
            });
```

> UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException has been thrown
> UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.

In addition, I get this message:

> This call site is reachable on: 'iOS' 15.0 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.0 and later. 'UIApplication.OpenNotificationSettingsUrl' is only supported on: 'ios' 15.4 and later, 'maccatalyst' 15.4 and later, 'tvos' 15.4 and later.

How can I open my game's push notification settings on iOS? Is it possible to do this in MonoGame?

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649524-getnotificationsettings "Your app may execute this block on a background thread." Any code you run from the completion handler that needs to run on UI thread requires synchronizing with the UI thread.

Comment: You need to dispatch the open onto the main thread. Also, if the current status is `.notDetermined` then the appropriate response is to request notification permission in your app, not redirect to app settings. If you have never asked for notification permissions then there is no app setting to change.

Comment: It works now. I use MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {additional code}); before I execute the additional code.